# Center Images With Foundation Block Grid

Tags: html, image, css, zurb-foundation

This is the page I am working on:
http://lorenpaulcaplin.com/jve/illustrations.html

My client wants the images to be center aligned instead of being lined up by their left sides.

If this were text I'd just use `text-align:center`, but life is not that easy. Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10989238/center-align-image-within-div-horizontally), I tried this:

```
ul.small-block-grid-3 img {
    display:block;
    margin:auto; 
}
```

but no luck:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `text-align:center` to your `li` elements.

Something like this:

```
.fairy > ul > li {
  text-align:center;
}
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/h3CQ8/).

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you. Can you explain why text-align worked on images? I'm kind of confused as to why it aligned non-text elements.

Comment: The naming of the element is a little confusing. It's easier to think of it as a 'content-align' than just 'text-align'. It should `center-align` any `inline-block` element.  If your image was a `block` element you would need to use the `margin: 0 auto;` method.