# centering images within a sidebar

Tags: html, css, sidebar

trying to do best practices here and I'm new to coding. I have two images in a right sidebar. Sidebar looks good (colored it red so I could see what's up) but I can't get the two images centered in a column. What's wrong with my css?

html:

```html
<div class="right_bar">
  <div class="sponsor_button"><img src="images/nav_images/uconn-grant-logo.png" alt="Sponsored in part by the University of Connecticut's Research Grant";></div class="sponsor_button">
     <div><img src="images/nav_images/usitt.png" alt="Sponsored in part by USITT";>      
  </div>
    </div>
```

css:

```css
.right_bar {
 position:absolute;
 right:0;
 width: 20%;
 background-color: red;
 
}

.sponsor_button img {
 margin-left:auto;
 margin-right:auto;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Center align image within div horizontally](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10989238/center-align-image-within-div-horizontally)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `display: block` on the images for `margin: 0 auto` to work:

```
.sponsor_button img {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Or you could try `text-align: center` on the container:

```
.right_bar {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `display:inline` to get it in the same column...

```css
.right_bar {
 position:absolute;
 right:0;
 width: 20%;
 background-color: red;
 
}

.sponsor_button img {
        display:inline;
 margin-left:auto;
 margin-right:auto;
}
```