# How do I center the image in my header and store it for other pages?

Tags: html, css, image, header

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<title>HEX</title> 
</head>

<header>
<img src="header.png" alt="head"/>
</header>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

This first Section is the html I am using, any improvements will help me a lot! I need to get this image in the center of my page and maybe store the header as a separate file so I can use it on every page of the site! I currently don't have anything in my css file as things I have tried are not working!!

Comment: You forgot your opening body tag

Comment: This question was answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10989238/center-align-image-within-div-horizontally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<link rel="import" href="your_imported_HTML.html">

this will also import any scripts,css that are in the imported html file
```

Answer (score 0):

Place your image in a div and use `margin auto`, allowing for any text or other content using css.

You can save the header as a separate php file (e.g., `header.php`), then include the file in any other pages using `include('header.php')`.
in the html body part.

Example:

```
<body>   
include ('header.php')
```

Use this in each page for the same effect.