# How to center an image within a div?

Tags: html, image, center

I know the center tag is out dated, so what is a better way to do it?

I am trying to center an image within a div.

Comment: You need to use css, check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10989238/center-align-image-within-div-horizontally

Comment: More detail.... are you trying to center vertically? Horizontality? Some example code maybe?

Comment: Sorry, horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
text-align: center
```

for horizontal centering