# How to align an image horizontally center within a div?

Tags: html, css

**I have this below HTML Code:**

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
  <div class="answer-picture col-xs-12" id="bookListDiv">
    <div id="loadme" style="display:block; margin:0 auto">
      <img src="~/images/loader.gif" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10989238/center-align-image-within-div-horizontally) and lot more but couldn't align it to center.

Comment: text-align:center

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Center align image within div horizontally](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10989238/center-align-image-within-div-horizontally)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

apply style text-align:center to div as:

```html
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
     <div class="answer-picture col-xs-12" id="bookListDiv">
           <div id="loadme" style="display:block; margin:0 auto;text-align:center">
                <img src="~/images/loader.gif"/>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: So I missed the `text-align:center`! and had figure out this for 8 hrs this is insane.... Thank you for that though.

Answer (score 0):

Add only this css to #loadme{text-align:center;}

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
  <div class="answer-picture col-xs-12" id="bookListDiv">
    <div id="loadme" style="display:block; text-align:center">
      <img src="~/images/loader.gif" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do This ..

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
  <div class="answer-picture col-xs-12" id="bookListDiv">
    <div id="loadme" class="text-center" style="display:block; margin: 0 auto !important;">
      <img src="~/images/loader.gif" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The DIV containing your IMG should be a `display: block;`
The image should be a `display: inline-block;` or its initial state;
By default images or any `display: inline-block;` objects are much treated like text, so you'll have to assign `text-align: center;` to your DIV;

Hope this helps you in future.

Answer (score 0):

In css,

```
#loadme { display:grid; align-items:center;}
```

Using CSSGrid