# Image is not centered horizontally in the middle of the page

Tags: html

This is my simple code:

```html
<h1 style="text-align:center;">Title TEST</h1>
<img class="center" src="MyImage.jpg">
<footer>
  <p style="text-align:center;">Footer TEST</p>
</footer>
```

Text is centered correctly, the image not.. Why? I can't understand

Comment: there is nothing saying it should be, you have centred the h1 and paragraphs but not the image

Comment: Do you have CSS to go with this? If so post it please.

Comment: @Pete `class="center"`

Comment: Possibly duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10989238/center-align-image-within-div-horizontally?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: @Pete Which is why I'm asking the OP if they have a stylesheet

Answer (score 1):

In your current attempt, `class="center"` would have no meaning unless you have a class called `.center` defined in your CSS. It doesn't look like you have a stylesheet, though.

Here are two ways to center an image horizontally:

1. Use `text-align: center` on a parent element:

```html
<div style="text-align: center;">
  <h1>Title TEST</h1>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" />
  <footer>
    <p>Footer TEST</p>
  </footer>
</div>
```

2. Center the image element itself by making it `block`-level and giving it a `margin-left` and `margin-right` of `0`:

```html
<h1 style="text-align: center;">Title TEST</h1>
<img style="display: block; margin: 0 auto;" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" />
<footer>
  <p style="text-align: center;">Footer TEST</p>
</footer>
```

Comment: @user3518663 Glad it helped, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please feel free to click the checkmark icon next to the most helpful answer to close the question.